# One database structure with many databases, or one global database?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Question is this:

Should we have 1 database per vertical or 1 database for everything?  Site will contain several for sale ads.

A) 1 db per vertical example
Meaning, when you view these pages:
http://www.site.com/cars
http://www.site.com/boats

/cars literally connects to a database lets say "db_cars" and that database ONLY has car data, nothing else in it.
/boats literally connects to a database lets say "db_boats" and that database ONLY has boat data, nothing else in it.

Both databases have the same structure, table names "item" "seller" etc

OR

B) 1 db for everything example
/cars connects to "db_everything" and filters cars based on a table linked to the items table, so WHERE item_type="cars"
/boats connects to "db_everything" and filters cars based on a table linked to the items table, so WHERE item_type="boats"

So would you pick A or B?  Any pros/cons to either?  Does it matter if it's MySQL, Oracle or Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents:

I would use separate databases for separate apps, not for separate kinds of data within one app.

Do you want to show boats and cars in the same app? On the same page?  Do you ever do an SQL query that should return both cars and boats?

Or are you basically treating boats and cars as completely separate web sites?  If they are completely separate, and could be supported separately, and could have the app modified separately, then it makes sense to use separate databases.

Answer (score 0):

A consideration that springs to mind is re-usability of site code. Controlling separate db username:password combinations across hundreds of categories sounds annoying.

Performance-wise, I think the separation becomes irrelevant unless your separate databases are on separate machines.

Also depends on your use...

Long-term, keeping them in one db probably gives you more flexibility and opportunity to generate trend data, or cross-link categories.

But, if you are making an engine to sell to other companies in specific industries, then 1 db per vertical makes sense.

My own inclination would be case B, unless a specific need told me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the databases are on the same server under the same user, you can still do joins and such. But i’d only recommend this if you need more than 30 tables for one section of your site.
It keeps management easy when you have to work directly in the database.

But if your site doesnt require such an level of complexity, I would advice against it, its not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does it matter if it's MySQL, Oracle or Postgres?*

Absolutely.

The term "database" in Oracle means something completely different than in most other databases. If you are thinking "database" in MySQL or Postgres (or SQL Server) you would normally think "schema" (=user) in Oracle.

In PostgreSQL you are not able to do cross-database queries. So for separation, schemas are probably better (because it's more flexible).

Regarding your the actual design decision: It sounds like you probably want to have everything in one database/schema but there is not enough information to really answer that.

wegjprgm's answer pretty much nails it down I think.